# Detect custom domain (subdomain.domain.com) that made the request to lambda functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda

I deployed my nodejs app to aws lambda functions using serverless.
I am using route53 and cloudfront for custom domain usage.
I make requests to lambda functions through different subdomains.
How to detect what is the subdomain that was used to make the request?
I am new to aws. I was using google cloud before and I am trying to shift to aws. In firebase I used to get the request url through req.headers["x-forwarded-host"] or req.headers.referrer (not sure which one now) and it was returning subdomain.domain.com

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by "make requests to lambda functions through different subdomains"? Are you using API Gateway, or are you directly invoking the Lambda function? More information, please.

Comment: Hi John, I'm using Route53 and Cloudfront